# Making a simple scoreboard with sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-center

So I have seen some totorials around that tell how to make a scoreboard using the Game Center API.  Don't get me wrong I love the idea of Game Center, but I dont want my users to have to fuddle with logging in and I dont want to use their way of displaying scores because it does not match the style of the game.

Does anyone know of a better way to do this so I can decide how to display the scoreboard?  All I want to do is tell the user his numerical rank like "rank: 1054", and then display the top 100 users (each user has their best score up).  And then if I could just have an array with a string for their name, and numbers for their score.  I am fine using the Game Center API as long as I dont have to use it for displaying it.

Also is their a way I could make like an "int" that is stored on Game Center that keeps track of how many times the play button has been pressed for all users?  Thanks much!

Comment: exactly what stage are you at here? do you already know how to make a database in order to store users and do you already have a server system set up to communicate with the user's phone and send/receive information between user and database? These are the types of questions you should be asking yourself if you are doing away with game center...

Comment: I have never made a database in my life.

Comment: I realize that, which is precisely why its probably best to work with Game Center since Apple pretty much does everything for you, even if the user has the log in

Comment: Well I once had an sql database for a minecraft server but that doesn't really count.

Comment: So how would you grab data from gamecenter instead of having them display it?

Comment: Using the game center UI elements... read the game center documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH1-SW1